# FUNCION Y CONDICIONALES PYTHON

Tags: python, funciones

Realizá una función llamada recortar() que reciba tres parámetros. El primero es el número a recortar, el segundo es el límite inferior y el tercero el límite superior. La función tendrá que cumplir lo siguiente:

1. Devolver el límite inferior si el número es menor que éste
2. Devolver el límite superior si el número es mayor que éste.
3. Devolver el número sin cambios si no se supera ningún límite.
   Comprueba el resultado de recortar 15 entre los límites 0 y 10

#EJERCICIO 5

```
def recortar(numero,inferior,superior):
    if inferior < numero and numero > inferior:
        return inferior
    if superior > numero and numero < superior:
        return superior
    else:
        return numero


print(recortar(15,0,19))
```

AL COLOCAR UN 10 COMO TERCER PARAMETRO DEVUELVE LA PRIMERA CONDICION SIN NINGUN PROBLEMA.
EL ERROR SUCEDE CUANDO SE CAMBIA EL TERCER PARAMETRO QUE SUPERA AL PRIMERO Y DEVUELVE CERO.

ME PARECE QUE HAY UN ERROR DE SINTAXIS POR LO QUE NO SE EJECUTA LAS DEMAS CONDICIONES. AGRADECERIA TODA IDEA QUE CREAN CONVENIENTE.

Comment: En internet, las mayusculas sostenidas son interpretadas como gritar. Te recomiendo sacarlas.

Comment: Escribir con mayúsculas es considerado gritar. En ambos `if` tienes 2 veces la misma condición. `inferior < numero` es lo mismo que `numero > inferior`, lo mismo haces con el segundo `if`. Te recomiendo repasar los signos [mayor que y menor que](https://www.todamateria.com/mayor-que-y-menor-que/)

Answer (score 3):

Lo mejor es siempre escribir la condición como la dices: "si el número es menor que inferior"

```
if numero < inferior:
```

Igualmente:

```
 elif numero > superior:
```

La función queda

```
def recortar(numero,inferior,superior):
    if numero < inferior:
        return inferior
    elif numero > superior:
        return superior
    else:
        return numero
```

Comment: @FranciscoJavier. Gracias

Comment: Gracias a todos ahi me quedo claro!! creo que sabia por donde iba pero me clarificaron como finalizarlo. Desde ya muchas gracias y agradezco la velocidad de respuesta.

Comment: [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)